# Barebones Audio Recorder - initial load not recording

Tags: flash, recording

I have bought the plugin Barebones Recorder but it behaves incorrectly when loaded first time.

http://recorder.denniehoopingarner.com/htmlinterface.html

Steps to repeat the bug:
I use Windows 8.1 64 bit, Flash player 13, Firefox 29.0.1. I use above demo.

1. I restart computer (that is the only way I figure out how to unload certain component, don't know which). Closing Flash Player process, firefox, cleaning all data in browser does not reproduce the bug.
2. I open above demo link
3. I grant permission - and microphone never gets input different then -1.

That is the problem. Most users are first time users.

When I refresh the page and repeat the process from now on it works as expected until I restart pc.

Has anyone used it and can help me? Unfortunately this flash plugin is a black box.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that barebones recorder is no different then other plugins (wami-recorder) and windows applications (audio recorder). I have traced that short after system boot, after first time recording functionality is requested process "audio graph isolation" takes a lot of resources. Until it does what is needs the initialization is pending. Sometimes it takes 10seconds! or more. So what I do instead of relying just on recorder initialization status I analyze samples. Until they are positive - I show initialization message. For barebones that is using this global function:

```js
function recorderMeter(x) {
    if (!IsMicrophoneReady && x > -1) {
        IsMicrophoneReady = true;
        // start recording, real microphone init is finished
    }
}
```